# Can I make a cooccurence network with groups clustered spacially in R?

Tags: r

I'd like to make a figure like the image below - a microbiome cooccurrence network grouped spatially by phyla. I have the list of nodes and edges, I'm just looking for a simply way to ordinate them in space as groups. Any ideas? Thanks

Example dataframes if that's helpful

```
#nodes
id label group
1 species1 1
2 species2 1
3 species3 2
4 species4 2
5 species5 2
6 species6 3
7 species7 3
8 species8 3
9 species9 3
10 species10 3

#edges
from to
1 2
1 3 
3 4 
2 5 
2 4 
2 7
5 7
5 8 
6 9 
6 10
```

[image]

Comment: If you do not provide code and data we cannot help you. Of course, drawing network diagrams is possible with R, see e.g. packages `networkD3` and `igraph`.

Comment: I don't have any code, my problem is I don't know where to start. I have a dataframe which is too big to share. I will try and make a mock up one but all it would be is:
1 groupA
2 groupA
1 groupB
2 groupB
3 groupA
3 groupB etc
 I just want package/method recommendations for things that could potentially make a figure like this. I have been using igraph but can't find a way to do an arrangement this yet. Thanks

Comment: Provide group assignement, nodes and edges for your first ten rows, if those cover more than one group. You can use `dput(dataframename[1:10, ])` for this.

Comment: Thanks, just working out how to put it in the post text

Comment: Hi, I've added a simplified version of my top 10 rows

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.